# PHP issue with displaying json results

Tags: php, json

First of all, I am extremely new to PHP, so I am still trying. My issue is: I am trying to echo Bing API results in PHP.

Here is a JSON result example, which I get from

```
$jsonobj = json_decode($response);
```

(The response is what I get from Bing, so I just pasted the response below - Just adding this info in case you wonder where I get the `$jsonobj = json_decode($response);` from)

```
{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Composite?Sources=\u0027web\u0027&Market=\u0027en-US\u0027&Query=\u0027php\u0027&Adult=\u0027off\u0027&$skip=0&$top=1","type":"ExpandableSearchResult"},"ID":"1c509d25-5ca4-4db5-bfc5-cafd6917e2c2","WebTotal":"10600000","WebOffset":"0","ImageTotal":"","ImageOffset":"","VideoTotal":"","VideoOffset":"","NewsTotal":"","NewsOffset":"","SpellingSuggestionsTotal":"","AlteredQuery":"","AlterationOverrideQuery":"","Web":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid\u00271c509d25-5ca4-4db5-bfc5-cafd6917e2c2\u0027)/Web?$skip=0&$top=1","type":"WebResult"},"ID":"4cf2a8d6-21b7-433d-81e9-84e74091a44a","Title":"PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor","Description":"What is PHP? PHP is a widely-used general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited for Web development and can be embedded into HTML.","DisplayUrl":"www.php.net","Url":"http://www.php.net/"},{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid\u00271c509d25-5ca4-4db5-bfc5-cafd6917e2c2\u0027)/Web?$skip=48&$top=1","type":"WebResult"},"ID":"2d8f8107-895e-4052-9edc-b656e74c3f2e","Title":"CakePHP: the rapid development php framework. Pages","Description":"Official website. Offers a manual for beginners and links towards the last version.","DisplayUrl":"cakephp.org","Url":"http://cakephp.org/"},{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid\u00271c509d25-5ca4-4db5-bfc5-cafd6917e2c2\u0027)/Web?$skip=49&$top=1","type":"WebResult"},"ID":"816d781c-ff8b-4a60-b5b7-28d807bba28a","Title":"PHP Presents","Description":"Welcome to the PHP Presentation System. Here we list all of the available presentation categories stored within this system.","DisplayUrl":"talks.php.net","Url":"http://talks.php.net/"}],"Image":[],"Video":[],"News":[],"RelatedSearch":[],"SpellingSuggestions":[]}]}}
```

Now, I understand that I can echo, for example, the WebTotal by using:

```
foreach($jsonobj->d->results as $value) {
    echo $value->WebTotal;
}
```

However, I am lost on how to echo the actual results like the `Title`, `Description` and `Url`.

I tried:

```
foreach($jsonobj->d->results as $value) {
    echo $value->Title."<br>";
    echo $value->Description."<br>";
    echo $value->Url."<br>";
}
```

and also something like:

```
foreach($jsonobj->d->results->Web as $value) {
    echo $value->Title."<br>";
    echo $value->Description."<br>";
    echo $value->Url."<br>";
}
```

because I thought adding the Web to the `foreach` will maybe echo the right values, but no success.

Maybe someone could help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

My mission would be to have the following results:

> Title: PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor
>
> Description: What is PHP? PHP is a widely-used general-purpose
>   scripting language that is especially suited for Web development and
>   can be embedded into HTML.
>
> URL:http://www.php.net/

Then, the other two results.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Sometimes it helps to print out a formatted version of the object to better understand where these elements are. :) `printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($value, 1));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
foreach($jsonobj->d->results as $result) {
    foreach($result->Web as $value) {
        echo $value->Title;
        // and the same for the other properties
    }
}
```

By the way: you should use a tool for formatting your json string. This way it will get much clearer how the json data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

First to use print_r method so you can see how is the object look like and so you can determine where to start the loop.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($jsonobj);
```

Then change the type to array like $array = (array) $jsonobj; so you can use it for array_shift function ( you can use this function adjust your array)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Comment: It will help you to debug the array first so youll easily know where to start the loop instead of using a long method chaining

Comment: See my first comment. Simply printing out the object will accomplish that. There's no need for the recast and array_shift() ;)